# how to use generics in Java with language operators and generic class extending Number

Tags: java, generics, operators

I would like to perform an operation on two generics argument of the same type both extending Number.

Is it Possible? 
I always used to call methods on generic arguments, but seems there is some problem using operators (The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T).

```
public static <T extends Number> T sum(T a, T b){
    return a+ b;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I try to improve a little bit my question. I understood that operators are not defined for type Number. It's a bit sad this thing because it would be nice to perform such an operation without introducing new interfaces like suggested by @Victor Sorokin.

But I still don't understand one thing: if operators are not implemented in the class Number, then at least in Double class should be implemented because I can use + operator with double.
Neither these line of code will compile:

```
public static <T extends Double> T sum(T a, T b){

    T c = a +b;
}
```

why?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to do that? What does the error say?

Comment: `+` is not defined for `Number`!

Comment: it doesn't compile. Eclipse says: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

Comment: @thomson_matt @Victor Sorokin @Oli Charlesworth thank you all for the help. I edited my question.

Comment: Your new example doesn't compile for a different reason.  At run-time, the JVM doesn't know what type of `T` it should construct, due to *type erasure*.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: thanks. how can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Why is it still not working after Auto Unboxing is introduced? My generic type clearly states `<T extends Number>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible because `Number` doesn't have a + operator associated with it.  In particular, you can't do this:

```
Number a = new Integer(1);
Number b = new Integer(2);
Number c = a + b;
```

Comment: Actually, not a cast, you missed `new` keyword ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `+` operator for classes in Java (except String and there's implicit conversion for other types via `toString()` when one of arguments is String). So, make you type implement some interface, say

```
interface Valuable {
    // use richest built-in numeric type
    double value();
    Valuable value(double v);
}

public static <T extends Valuable> T sum(T a, T b){
    return a.value(a.value() + b.value());
}
```

Ugly, isn't it? =D

---

**Fix 2022** code above is wrong, as `Valuable#value` can't produce instance of subtype `T`, so we need to go a bit more hairy:

```
interface Valuable<T extends Valuable<T>> {
    // use richest built-in numeric type
    double value();
    T value(double v);
}

class Impl implements Valuable<Impl> {
    private final double v;

    Impl(double v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public double value() {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Impl value(double v) {
        return new Impl(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Impl{" +
                "v=" + v +
                '}';
    }
}

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Impl a = new Impl(1), b = new Impl(-1);
        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + sum(a, b));
    }

    public static <T extends Valuable<T>> T sum(T a, T b){
        return a.value(a.value() + b.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? I get an compile time error in the sum method: `error: incompatible types: Valuable cannot be converted to T
    return a.value(a.value() + b.value());`

Comment: @math you're right! I've fixed the answer )