# Generic type subtraction in Java

Tags: java

I have a Pair class of Generic Type and the following way of subtraction gives me error as `the operator - is not defined for T,T`. I searched and found that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601015/how-to-use-generics-in-java-with-language-operators-and-generic-class-extending). I wonder it is the only way of operator overloading in Java. I think not straightforward. I came from C++ background. Thanks

```
public class Pair<T>{


    private T first;
    private T second;

    public T firstpairSub(Pair<T> s) {
        return this.first - s.first;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to do this, you could use Scala, which, in the end, compiles to java

Comment: Besides that operator overloading is not possible in Java, as you don't even make any assumptions about `T`, this is simply wrong, because anyone could extend your class with type `Object`, `String` or `List`.

Comment: Java generics do not work in the same way as C++ templates. Generics are not a template from which different implementations are generated, like in C++. You'll need to unlearn thinking about generics as if they are templates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)

Comment: If overloading is not allowed in Java, why Generic type is allowed in Java. Quiet frustrating

Comment: I know a lot of people discussed. But I like to have a discussion to convince myself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload operators in Java.

The subtraction operator is only defined for numeric types.

What would you expect that to produce for, say, a `Pair<String>`? What about a `Pair<Socket>` or a `Pair<java.sql.Driver>`?

Comment: Yes if you have to use two Sockets for your application, you can wrap it in a pair and it makes Socket1 and Socket2. It makes sense to me.

Comment: His point is, that your method firstPairSub would fail, if the Pair was of type Socket.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the conversion yourself:

```
public class Pair<T extends Number>{

...

public T firstpairSub(Pair<T> s) throws Exception{
    if(this.first instanceof Integer && s.first instanceof Integer)
        return (Number) ((Integer)this.first- (Integer)s.first);
    if(this.first instanceof Double && s.first instanceof Double)
    ...

    throw new Exception("Invalid type")

}
```

Comment: So what is the point of Making Generic T if I have to use instanceof. I'll have a lot of instanceof.